# Среда разработки javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть ли среда разработки для javascript похожая на visual c#? Чтобы при наведении курсора на метод, выводилось описание.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

Comment: WebStorm - the best!

Answer (score 1):

Может, [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/javascript/index_ru.html)?

> Используйте функции полной подсветки синтаксиса, автозавершения кода, всплывающие подсказки документации и проверку ошибок для HTML, CSS и JavaScript, включая HTML 5, JavaScript 1.7 и семантическую подсветку для E 4X (внедренных объектов XML). Редактор распознает код HTML в файлах JavaScript и коде JavaScript в файлах HTML. Также редактор распознает HTML и код JavaScript в файлах XHTML, PHP и JSP.

Answer (score 0):

[**редактор для javascript**](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+javascript&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Answer (score 0):

Komodo edit - бесплатная, быстрая, удобная, без 100500 настроек ( это я про eclipse ), есть версии под win, unix, mac. Так-же имеется поддержка html5, jquery, nodejs и огромного количества языков и технологий ( например EJS ). По сравнению с NetBeans явный плюс это скорость работы, по сравнению с webstorm - komodo edit бесплатна.